# Fun with Pandas `rolling_apply` and TypeError

Tags: python, pandas

I'm really struggling with the Pandas `rolling_apply function`. I'm trying to apply a filter to some time series data like below and make a new series for outliers. I want the value to return `True` when the value is an outlier.

```
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))

window, alpha, gamma = 60, .05, .03

def trim_moments(arr, alpha):
    np.sort(arr)
    n = len(arr)
    k = int(round(n*float(alpha))/2)
    return np.mean(arr[k+1:n-k]), np.std(arr[k+1:n-k])

# First function that tests whether criteria is met.
def bg_test(arr,alpha,gamma):
    local_mean, local_std = trim_moments(arr, alpha)
    return np.abs(arr - local_mean) < 3 * local_std + gamma
```

This is the function that I run

```
outliers = pd.rolling_apply(ts, window, bg_test, args=(alpha,gamma))
```

Returns the error:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

My troubleshooting indicates that the problem lies in the boolean return statement. I keep getting the similar error when I simplify the function and use `np.mean/std` rather than my own functions. It seems like previous issues with `TypeError` were due to performing non-vectorized operations on Numpy Arrays but this doesn't seem to be the issue here.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's less than a helpful message, but I believe the error is happening because `rolling_apply` currently expects a like typed return array (may even have to be float).  But, if you break your three operations (mean, std, outlier logic) into steps, it should work ok.

```
ts.name = 'value'

df = pd.DataFrame(ts)

def trimmed_apply(arr, alpha, f):
    np.sort(arr)
    n = len(arr)
    k = int(round(n*float(alpha))/2)
    return f(arr[k+1:n-k])

df['trimmed_mean'] = pd.rolling_apply(df['value'], window, trimmed_apply, args=(alpha, np.mean))
df['trimmed_std'] = pd.rolling_apply(df['value'], window, trimmed_apply, args=(alpha, np.std))

df['outlier'] = np.abs(arr - df['trimmed_mean']) < 3 *  df['trimmed_std'] + gamma
```

Comment: I would like to thank you not only for the solution that works but also for how you organized the `trim_apply` function. Quite handy! Surprisingly this is only speeding up my previous solution (done via `pd.iterrows()` by 3-5x. I was expecting better gains from avoiding iteration.