# pandas rolling_apply to handle object types like pandas.TimeGrouper

Tags: python, pandas

Related to [Fun with Pandas `rolling_apply` and TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459624/fun-with-pandas-rolling-apply-and-typeerror) and [Using rolling_apply on a DataFrame object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121854/using-rolling-apply-on-a-dataframe-object/25632626#25632626)

Suppose F is a function that returns a function and df is a Series with a datetime index.

The following seems to work:

```
df.groupby(pandas.TimeGrouper('10d')).apply(F)
```

while the following results in a TypeError as rolling_apply seems to expect floats as return values.

```
pandas.rolling_apply(df, 10, F)
```

I actually want the latter as I want to groupby each window of 10 available days and not the available data from each 10-day window as I think TimeGrouper does.

Is there a direct way to do this using some other function?

For a concrete example, this appears to be working:

```
from statsmodels.tools.tools import ECDF
s = pandas.Series(randn(1000))
s.index = pandas.date_range('2012-01-01', periods=s.shape[0], freq='D')
f = s.groupby(pandas.TimeGrouper('30D')).apply(ECDF)
f.apply(lambda x: x(0.1)).head()
```

Comment: If `F` is a function that returns a function, then I'm not sure how `df.groupby(pandas.TimeGrouper('10d')).apply(F)` is going to work. Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: I've added an example with a function returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is a hack, but you could at least achieve your goal like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tools.tools import ECDF

s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000))
s.index = pd.date_range('2012-01-01', periods=s.shape[0], freq='D')
result = []
pd.rolling_apply(s, 10, lambda grp: result.append(ECDF(grp)) or 1)
print([f(0.1) for f in result])
```

The lambda function

```
lambda grp: result.append(ECDF(grp)) or 1
```

stores the ECDFs in the `result` list. Since `result.append` returns `None`, the expression `result.append(ECDF(grp)) or 1` resolves to the numerical value 1 so `pd.rolling_apply` does not raise an error.