# How to use pandas rolling apply

Tags: python, pandas

The task is to use customized functions (panel_garch1) with Pandas 'rolling apply', it uses another package called 'arch', which is used to forecast volatilities, firstly let's get some data:

```
import numpy as np
from arch.univariate import GARCH, EGARCH, ConstantMean, Normal
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.data import DataReader

aapl = DataReader('AAPL',  'yahoo', datetime(2006,1,1), datetime(2016,3,10))
returns = pd.DataFrame(np.diff(np.log(aapl['Adj Close'].values)))
returns.index = aapl.index.values[1:aapl.index.values.shape[0]]
returns.columns = ['AAPL Returns']
```

return data looks like this

```
2006-01-04  0.002939
2006-01-05  -0.007901
2006-01-06  0.025486
2006-01-09  -0.003282
2006-01-10  0.061328
2006-01-11  0.036906
2006-01-12  0.004638
2006-01-13  0.015305
2006-01-17  -0.010335
2006-01-18  -0.026557
2006-01-19  -0.042723
```

A simple function 'compute_mean' works pretty well

```
def compute_mean(ret):
    return np.mean(ret)
returns.rolling(center=False, window=12).apply(compute_mean)
```

Now I want to use this function below

```
def panel_garch1(df_ret):
    ret = df_ret
    am = ConstantMean(ret)
    am.volatility = EGARCH(1, 0, 1)
    am.distribution = Normal()
    cond_vol = am.fit(update_freq=0, disp='off').conditional_volatility
    return cond_vol
```

It works fine if I just use it alone, returns can be either dataframe or numpy array

```
panel_garch1(returns)
```

Then if I try to apply it to rolling window, it wouldn't work

```
returns.rolling(center=False, window=12).apply(panel_garch1)
```

or

```
pd.rolling_apply(returns, 12, lambda x: panel_garch1(x))
```

Pandas will complain

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

What's the problem here? I've already read something on stackoverflow, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459624/fun-with-pandas-rolling-apply-and-typeerror), but the answers to those questions do not apply to this case. Thank you very much!

Comment: `cond_vol` has to be either a scalar or an array with length 1. Apparently `panel_garch1` sometimes returns vectors.

Comment: I see, now I figured out the problem, thank you @cel

Comment: How did you solve this problem @apt142857, I am having a similar question with pd.rolling

Comment: @BobeKryant, the function in apply() must return a scalar, otherwise you are trying to pass a column to an element in one column, i.e. in the end of panel_garch1, return cond_vol[-1]